How to target a specific endpoint with swagger ui and spring boot gateway
We were using JMX to be able to access (debug) information about our process as the content of a specific store, and sometimes trigger things as a forced reload. We now want to do it with actuators, and want to expose our actuators with swagger. To avoid to have to expose one route by microservice instance, a spring cloud gateway centralizing all the swagger definitions looks like a goodsolution.
Springdoc has demo applications, including one showing how we can use spring cloud gateway to centralize swagger for all of our microservices, avoiding to expose many routes.
But if I take the code of the demo, and change one of the microservice to allow multiple instances (server.port=0 for a random port instead of a hard coded one), then I can see that I have no way to select which instance of the micro service I am talking with. There is a drop down with the list of servers, but it always contains the URL of the gateway.
Is there a way to have an option to target a specific replica, either through the list of servers, or through the list of definition?
Here the live demo with only one instance of each microservice

https://demos.springdoc.org/demo-microservices/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html
Here the code of the demo without my modifications to run on random ports:
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master

Or should we stick to JMX and something like spring boot admin?
